# Specify port for cRLDistributionPoint?

Tags: certificate-revocation, x.509

`cRLDistributionPoints` is OID 2.5.29.31. Here's what one looks like under Gutmann's `dumpasn1`:

```
SEQUENCE {
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER cRLDistributionPoints (2 5 29 31)
  OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
    SEQUENCE {
      SEQUENCE {
        [0] {
          [0] {
            [6] 'http://crl.example.com/crt1-crl.crl'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Are clients required to support, for example, `http://crl.example.com/crt1-crl.crl:8080`? Or is the an additional field available to specify the port?

Answer (score 1):

A `cRLDistributionPoint` is an URL so you can specify the HTTP port in it. And clients have to support it, of course.